# Hide PHP Parameter from URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello i have the following page in wordpress

https://www.xxx.me/register/?role=freelancer

i need it be as below

https://www.xxx.me/register/freelancer

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP plugins to do custom URL rewrites.

You can also accomplish this via .htaccess rewrites, but you will have to update the relevant links in WP.

Comment: Yes, however could you show your efforts to solving your issue up to now?

Comment: RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^role=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^register\$ /register/%1/? [R=301,L]

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register\/(.*)\/$ /register/?role=$1 [L]`